# Prove that $G = \{\cos x + t \sin x: x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is an abelian group under multiplication

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

where $x$ is the angle

Closure is easy - Since $x$ is a real number, its $\cos$ component and $\sin$ component will be a real number.

Associative property -  I guess it means that $(\cos x + t\sin x) + c= \cos x + (t\sin x + c)$  , right?

I'm not able to figure out how to do prove the rest of the remaining properties - identity, inverse and commutative

Comment: Are t and x the elements of Group?

Comment: Wasn't mentioned. The title is the statement of the question.

Comment: Your argument doesn't prove closure - you need to show $(\cos x+t\sin x)(\cos y+t\sin y)$ is still in the set, ie of the form $\cos z+t\sin z$ for some $z\in\mathbb R$. This question would make a lot more sense if $t$ were replaced by $i=\sqrt{-1}$; could it be a typo?

Comment: Why would I need to show that (cos x+tsin x)(cos y+tsin y)?  @stewbasic

Comment: The elements of $G$ are of the form $\cos(x)+t\sin(x)$. In order for it to be closed under multiplication, multiplying two elements of $G$ must result in another element of $G$. So we need that $(\cos(x)\cos(y)+t^2\sin(x)\sin(y)) + t(\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y))$ is of the form $\cos(z)+t\sin(z)$. This is not true for every $t$, so your problem is incorrect as stated.

Comment: Simplifying more we see $( \cos x \cos y + t^2 \sin x \sin y ) + t ( sin(x+y))$ which tells you to use $z=x+y$, then $\cos x \cos y + t^2 \sin x \sin y = \cos (x+y)$ only works if $t^2=-1$.

Comment: Also, what you have written is not what associativity means for this (alleged) group. You have to take three different elements of the group, add them in two different ways [wrt. bracket placement], and show that both give the same result.

Comment: @M.Vinay This is a multiplicative group,just correcting.But otherwise,you're right.

Comment: The arguments above don't really prove that the products couldn't be written in the form $\cos x+t\sin x$ for some $x$. E.g. for $t=0$ we do have closure. But for $t$ sufficiently large, you can show that $G$ has a greatest element greater than $1$, which when multiplied by itself is greater than itself and hence not in $G$. As others have remarked, $t$ should probably be $\mathrm i$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Duh, of course! Forgot that just when I wrote the comment. Thanks for correcting.